# Language agnostic way to remove sensitive information from files before committing to Git

Tags: git, version-control, language-agnostic

What are the recommended procedures for automatically removing sensitive information from files before committing to Git?

For example, say I have the following in a file called `code.rb`:

```
personal_stuff = "some personal stuff"
```

How can I automatically remove the personal information from `code.rb` before committing to version control? The solution should be language-agnostic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a ["clean filter"](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html) for specific files is another way to go.

**Update** an example, as demanded:

Add a "clean" filter to the local repository configuration, consisting of one call to `sed`.  This could be a path to a shell script or to any program which consumes data on its standard input and writes processed data to its standard output:

```
$ git config --add filter.classify.clean \
    'sed -e '\''s!\<\(personal_stuff\s\+=\s\+\)"[^"]\+"!\1"SECRET"!'\'
```

Now Register our filter to be applied for files which names match `*.rb`:

```
$ cat >.gitattributes
*.rb    filter=classify
^D
```

Create a couple of test files:

```
$ cat >test.rb
aaa
bbb
        personal_stuff  = "sensitive data"
ccc
^D
$ cat >test.txt
aaa
xxx
personal_stuff = "super secret"
yyy
^D
```

Now add and commit them:

```
$ git add test.*
$ git commit -q -m 'root commit'
...
```

Now see what has happened to the contents of `test.rb`, that is, what does its blob in the just recorded commit contains:

```
$ git cat-file -p HEAD
tree 7adaac5cc23c69ff9459635d666ca63ffb9757aa
author Konstantin Khomoutov <flatworm@...ourceforge.net> 1368453302 +0400
committer Konstantin Khomoutov <flatworm@...ourceforge.net> 1368453302 +0400


root commit 
$ git cat-file -p 7adaa
100644 blob e49630236eb74d8c7ccbcccc83c7c18af0cb4b96    test.rb
100644 blob aecd9ade78e18d5b5ded99a1e41cf366fa52e619    test.txt
$ git cat-file -p e496302
aaa
bbb
        personal_stuff  = "SECRET"
ccc
```

Verify this did not affect the work tree:

```
$ cat test.rb
aaa
bbb
        personal_stuff  = "sensitive data"
ccc
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to do this?

Comment: Great answer! (extra characters)

Comment: @ZachLatta, thanks, but note that I personally prefer the answer which mvp gave: writing *proper* smudge filter is hard unless you know what you're looking for; in a general case it might be simpler to just scan for something that *looks* like security-sensitive data and simply fail if anything suspicious found, and this is what mvp proposes. So you should judge based on your specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to move your confidential informations to an external file which will be ignored.

There is two ways to ignore a file in git:

- Using the `.gitignore` file (permanent)
- Using the [git update-index](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/18/temporarily-ignoring-files.html) command (temporary)

In your case, the more flexible solution would be:

1. Create an empty files with fake personnal stuff (like `password = "mypassword1234"` or whatever...)
2. Commit and push this file
3. Ignore its futur modifications with `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged your_file`

Comment: It's not possible to move the confidential information to an external file because that's not language agnostic. The solution should work with any file, regardless of language or syntax. Your flexible solution won't work because I want to be able to change the file after I add the confidential information to it.

Comment: So you would like to be able to mask your confidential informations only when you push, without altering your code?

Comment: It is always possible to move the sensitive data to another file. If your language does not have an "include", use m4(1) to combine them first.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own [pre-commit hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). This hook will scan your code and decline commit if it can find something that it does not like.

Writing actual hook can be a challenge, you should be able to find [some](https://github.com/githubbrowser/Pre-commit-hooks) examples [online](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-git-commit-hooks-to-prevent-stupid-mistakes).

Comment: I think he wants to keep his confidential informations locally without send it to the server, don't to block the commit/push process.

Answer (score 1):

Use '.gitattributes' with '.gitfilters'.  Here is an example with 'rcs-keywords'; you'd follow the same structure but with filters for your sensitive data.

Your attributes files maps from file glob to filter, as such:

```
# .gitattributes
# Map file extensions to git filters
*.h filter=rcs-keywords
*.c filter=rcs-keywords
```

Your .gitfilters files implement a 'clean' and 'smudge' filter.  For the above 'rcs-keywords' filters this is:

```
$ ls .gitfilters/
rcs-keywords.clean*  rcs-keywords.smudge*
```

**The 'clean' filter removes stuff prior to commit; the 'smudge' filter adds stuff back on checkout**.

The filters are any script.  Again, for 'rcs-keywords' the 'clean' filter looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
s/\$Id[^\$]*\$/\$Id\$/; 
s/\$Date[^\$]*\$/\$Date\$/;
```

whereby rcs `Id` and `Date` information is removed.  The associated 'smudge' filter adds that information back in.

Lastly, you configure git as

```
git config --add filter.rcs-keywords.clean  .gitfilters/rcs-keywords.clean
git config --add filter.rcs-keywords.smudge .gitfilters/rcs-keywords.smudge
```

**For your case, the clean filter axes the sensitive data and the smudge filter adds it back in.**

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use .gitignore as you need to make parallel changes in the same file(as found in your comments) then one option is `git add -p`  Using this you can add or skip accordingly.

The problem using the above git command here is, it will be more of a manual process. I guess you may not find any other automated approach for you problem.